# How do I resolve the inability to get an input stream from URL?

Tags: java, image

I am unsure if anyone has ever had problems with this, but I am having difficulty trying to get the URL to work properly however, this is what the logs says

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

I am unsure now what to do and I hope some of you would be able to assist me.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8TpyQpSFyEPaGtxQzAxYzdRMFE

Comment: This is not an acceptable way to post such a question. You seem to expect readers to sieve through your source files and cobble together the code related to your ImageIO calls. You would have to present an http://sscce.org (minimal demonstration example). But I guess this comes down to image loading from a jar / resource, so answers kinda like the following are probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776177/getresourceasstream-returning-null-on-image-path